# Nodejs - array not returning anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to save the answer to my request with axios in an array, but I'm not getting it, is something wrong?

```
colorList = axios.get(colors);

let codes = [];

for (let i = 0; i < colorList.data.data.colors.length; i++) {
  codes[i].push(colorList.data.data.colors[i]);
}

console.log(codes);
```

Comment: maybe instead of `codes[i].push(colorList.data.data.colors[i]);` use `codes.push(colorList.data.data.colors[i]);`

Comment: did not work...

Comment: You need to wrap that in an async function and do `const response = await axios.get(colors);` Next you need to access `colorList.data` to get the actual response. And you can use `.map(...)` to transform it instead of the for loop. The first order of debugging is not to assume things; always, always `console.log()` everything.

Comment: oh sorry, you must await the `colorList`, `axios.get` return promise which you should resolve first before iterating over the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call is asynchronous meaning that you have to wait for your request to complete (or more accurately your promise from `axios.get()` to resolve) and do something with the result. Your code right now runs synchronously.

```
colorList = axios.get(colors).then(result =>{
  console.log(result)
});
```

EDIT: Or as a comment above noted, use an async/await setup. Keep in mind that you can't use await in top level code, it can only be used inside an `async function`

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const colorCodes = await axios.get(colors);
    } catch (e) {
        // handle error
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

If colorList.data.data.colors has values then try

codes.push(colorList.data.data.colors[i]);

Answer (score 0):

As most comments pointed out, the mistake in your code is that you don't await for the async call to be completed.The way that js works when you use async code is that it jumps to the next line immediatelly while the async process continues . That's the point of Async code: You don't want your program to freeze in case of async call delays. I made a similar code example using numbersapi.

```
var axios = require('axios');

const axiosCallToArray = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get('http://numbersapi.com/42');

  const wordsArray = result.data.split(' '); // here i create an array breaking the sentence (returned as result from axios) into words.Every word is an element of the new array

  console.log(wordsArray);
};

axiosCallToArray(); //now console.log works fine. This is valid also for your code
```